# Custom REST API in spring boot for creating Peers, Orderer, Channels etc in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: spring-boot, hyperledger-fabric

I have created a basic network in HLF

- Single Orderer
- 2 Organization, has 2 peers each
- Channel: finance

Now, If I wanted to add one more peer or create any other channel. I have to add the configuration in the crypto-config.yaml and configtxgen.yaml and execute peer and channel-related commands in the cli as per my understanding.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way that, I can create any REST API in spring boot to create the above process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK's available for adding peer's organization

Check this golang : [link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go)

Also there are different SDK for java, node.js.

Comment: but this SDK says, to use it to get easy access to the fabric network not to create the network. Our scripts are the only way to create a network. Are there no SDK APIs for that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but if you want to add a new organization or a new peer, you must use the fabric-SDK for those operations; this channel configuration updates will be the responsibility of an organization admin.

The SDK also provides a client for Hyperledger's certificate authority.

FABRIC SDK:

fabric-sdk-node doc: https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/

fabric-sdk-node: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/

fabric-sdk-java: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java

fabric-sdk-go: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go